# Regex to match URL, ends up matching URL plus closing brackets when URL is between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching, regex-group

I am using the following regex to match URLs within text

`` new RegExp(`(https?://\\S+\\.\\S+)\\s`, 'ig'); ``

The problem is when URL appear within brackets like this

`(e.g. https://hello.com/fridaysforfuture-eu-socialmedia)`

It picks off the closing bracket as part of the URL

My expected behavior is to include Closing bracket in the match if URL is like

`https://hello.com/name-(1)`

but exclude closing bracket if URL is within brackets like this

`(e.g. https://hello.com/fridaysforfuture-eu-socialmedia)`

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/Id7O7h/1) worked for me: `https?:\/\/\S+\.[^()]+(?:\([^)]*\))*`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use :

```
RegExp("(^|[\s.:;?\-\]<\(])(https?://[-\w;/?:@&=+$\|\_.!~*\|'()\[\]%#,☺]+[\w/#](\(\))?)(?=$|[\s',\|\(\).:;?\-\[\]>\)])","i")
```

Reference: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware parenthesis are not valid characters to appear in an URL (at least not unencoded)

There are a bunch of RegEx-Patterns for different use-cases in this question:

[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)